# Cancel button on VF page

Tags: visualforce, customsetting

I am developing a VF page to allow changes into a custom setting. And this page is set as a visualforce tab. I need a way to set up the cancel button such that it would take the user back to previous visited page.

Is there a way we can do that.

Answer (score 4):

While applying cancel operation visualforce you should stop the form validation.Use below any one methods to stop the form validation based on your requirements.

**Method 1:**

Using 
 **html-5 in doctype in visualforce page**
 means you should use **html-formnovalidate** and `immediate` in cancel button. For example

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!cancel}" value="Cancel" immediate="true" 
                    html-formnovalidate="formnovalidate" />
```

**Method 2:**

you should use `immediate` key word only need for stopping form validation. For Example

```
 <apex:commandButton action="{!cancel}" value="Cancel" immediate="true"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just as i finished asking the question. Read a post on stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8921434/how-to-implement-cancel-functionality-in-a-visualforce-page using standard controller and using the standard controllers cancel method.

Comment: Yep, that's the best way to do it.